# How to connect objects and keep it smooth?

Tags: mesh, smooth

When I want to join 2 meshes in one object this happen. I am using mirror and smooth modifier. How I can join 2 separated meshes into one object and keep it smooth? What I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: if you join 2 objects into one it won't merge the 2 meshes, you need to boolean or to merge manually to have one unique mesh. If this is the case here, what you're showing looks like inverted normals

Comment: I merged it manually it is one mest but it is not smooth anymore

Comment: so smooth again and check the normals? Also make sure you don't have overlapping vertices or innder faces

Comment: @moonboots yes I did it but it doesn´t help. Vhat is the correct wayto join 2 meshes and avoid that shape ?

Comment: Could you please share your file?

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do, you can click the first and then the second mesh, then right click go to join. After that, go to use the remesh modifier and adjust the voxel size and apply the modifier. As they said, it also looks like your normals are flipped wrong. Go to "view port overlays" in the top right and click on "normal orientation" to check that. If you see any red, then in edit mode, make sure all of your mesh is selected and go to "Mesh -> Normals ->Recalculate Outside". I would personally flip the normals first though.